# Creating threads within a multithreaded for loop using openMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am new to OpenMP and I am not able to create threads within each threaded loop iteration. My question may sound naive, please bear with me.

```
#pragma omp parallel private(a,b) shared(f)
{
     #pragma omp for 
      for(...)
     {
      //some operations
      // I want to parallelize the code in italics along within in the multi threaded for loop
      *int x=func1(a,b);*
      *int val1=validate(x);*
      *int y=func2(a,b);*
      *int val2=validate(y);*
      }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a paragraph at the bottom that explains what your actual question is. It is not clear from the code snippet.

Comment: I am able to parallelize a for loop, each for loop iterations has few sequential CPU functions. I want to run the functions using threads for each iteration of loop to save time.

Comment: It is beyond my understanding why you'd like to run those functions in parallel when the iterations of the loop are already distributed between all threads?

Answer (score 0):

Within the for loop all threads are busy with loop iterations, so there are no resources left to execute stuff in side an iteration in parallel. And in case the work is well balanced you won't gain any better performance.

If it is hard/impossible to well-balance the work with a parallel for. You can try generating tasks within the loop, and do the work afterwords. But be aware of the overhead of task generation.

```
#pragma omp parallel private(a,b) shared(f)
{
     #pragma omp for nowait
      for(...)
     {
      //some operations

      #pragma omp task
      {
      int x=func1(a,b);
      int val1=validate(x);
      }

      #pragma omp task
      {
      int y=func2(a,b);
      int val2=validate(y);
      }

     }

     // wait for all tasks to be finished (implicit at the end of the parallel region (here))
     #pragma omp taskwait      
}
```